# How to make a C Macro push data to a function

Tags: arrays, c, macros

I have written several traditional typed functions that I can use to manage a dynamically allocated array.  As a learning exercise, I am trying the same thing with some Macros.  Before anyone say's it, yes, I know that Macros should be used sparingly, but this is for the purpose of learning the dynamics and issues with Macros.

I have written a Macro to create structs with a pointer to an array of differing data types, a macro to initialize the vector struct, and another one to push data to the end of the stack.  Thus far it "appears" that everything is working, with exception of the line in `PUSH` where I add variable `_a` to the vector.  From the main function if I try to print the data, it appears as if the array is empty.  However, if from within the main function I conduct the exact same operation, it appears it works just fine.  I think this implies an issue within the Macro with the pointer to the `array` variable in the struct, but I am not sure.  Can anyone point out the flaw to me.

```c
#define VECTOR_STRUCT(type)                                                         \
    struct {type *array; size_t allocated_length; size_t active_length; }
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define INIT_VECTOR(vec, length) ({                                                     \
    size_t _a = (length);                                                               \
    typeof(vec.array) ptr = malloc(length * sizeof(*vec.array));                        \
    if (ptr == NULL) {                                                                  \
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed in file %s at line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);   \
        free(ptr);                                                                      \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                             \
    }                                                                                   \
    vec.allocated_length = _a;                                                          \
    vec.active_length = 0;                                                              \
    vec.array = ptr;                                                                    \
})
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define PUSH(vec, data) ({                                                                  \
    typeof(*vec.array) _a = (data);                                                         \
    if (vec.active_length + 1 > vec.allocated_length) {                                     \
        size_t new_size = vec.active_length * 2;                                            \
        typeof(vec.array) ptr = realloc(vec.array, new_size * sizeof(*vec.array));          \
        if (ptr == NULL) {                                                                  \
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed in file %s at line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);  \
            free(ptr);                                                                      \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                             \
        }                                                                                   \
        vec.array = ptr;                                                                    \
        vec.allocated_length = new_size;                                                    \
    }                                                                                       \
    vec.array[vec.active_length] = _a;                                                      \
    vec.active_length += 1;                                                                 \
})

int main() {
    VECTOR_STRUCT(int) int_vec;
    INIT_VECTOR(int_vec, 30);
    // Pushing to the vector with PUSH does not appear to work
    PUSH(int_vec, 15);
    PUSH(int_vec, 22)
    printf("%d\n", int_vec.array[0]);
    printf("%d\n", int_vec.array[1]);

    // pushing to the vector this way appears to work
    int_vec.array[0] = 32;
    int_vec.array[1] = 22;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", int_vec.array[i]);
    }
    free(int_vec.array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, you're making use of a GCC extension, "statement expressions".

Comment: @Barmar `typeof` is also an extension.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem here, but `length * sizeof(*vec.array)` should be `_a * sizeof(*vec.array)`

Comment: The code doesn't compile for me, there's a missing `;` after `PUSH(int_vec, 22)`. When I fix that, I get the expected output.

Comment: You also have undefined behavior at the end, you're printing `int_vec.array[2]`, which you never initialized.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for using text macros here. To learn use of macro start with thinking about cases where the macros are really necessary.

Comment: @Serge, can you provide an example of when they are absolutely necessary.  Also, why is there no reason to use a macro here.  I implemented this with traditional functions, and by the time I was done implementing every function, for every data type, the code base was literally 20 times longer.  I am struggling with the general perception that generics should not be implemented in C.  If this is the case, and time is money, then I find it hard to recommend any company use C which will lead to longer, and harder to maintain code.

Comment: @Serge To clarify my previous post, I trust what you are saying, especially since so many others are saying the same thing.  But, if this is the case, it will lead to much longer, harder to maintain code, which translates to more money spent on a company using C as a base language.  If this is true, then outside of building a Linux OS, or embedded programming, I am having a hard time understanding why any company would not gravitate to other languages with generic support.  Those languages come with problems, but the cost savings I think would outweigh the problems.

Comment: Just a hint to work around GCC's "statement expression": If you have statement-like macros, enclose the statements with `do { /* statements */ } while (0)`. This makes sure it works with other compilers, too, and throws compiler diagnostics if used as an expression. -- No professional team will implement every function for every data type up-front. They will only implement what they need. And then there is `_Generic`, do you know it?

Comment: @thebusybee, yes I do know the _Generic operator.  I disagree with your comment on data types as I have been part of teams that first built libraries in other languages with the requirement that it should work with any or a majority of data types.  This is done because they want the libraries to be flexible enough to handle problems that have yet to be thought of.

Comment: @Jon I do not understand how you ended up with longer code base in this case. Almost every macro you have is replaceable by an identical function. Using functions instead of macros will significantly simplify your life in writing and debugging your code. There are few scenarios where macros are useful: conditional compilation, creating variable names based on text parameters, replacing code which cannot be expressed as a function (like 'case' labels and others). Every where else avoid using macros.

Comment: So these teams had too much time to waste. Working for 30+ years in embedded industries, I never had this situation. :-D

Comment: @Serge, yes, one function for one data type.  If you want to implement the same function for multiple data types, you need to re-write the same function for each data type.

Comment: @thebusybee I have been an engineer for 20 years, albeit in the aerospace industry, and not as a software developer.  Your comment may be valid for embedded systems, in fact I believe it is, but not for other software use cases.  If it were valid then C++, JAVA, and other compiled and scripting languages would never have implemented generics.

Comment: Generics/templates are a different paradigm than a library full of potentially useful functions. I think you are aware that each usage with a different data type produces its own set of machine code. -- Yes, you can use macros for the same purpose, and in so far your approach makes some sense, when used for the needed data types. Using `_Generic` can be another option. -- BTW, the industry I'm specifically in is railway transportation, with comparable safety requirements as aerospace. -- However, your issue is resolved as a typo, and this is not the place to discuss meta stuff.